# Battleship in Python

Tags: python

I am a First Year Physics major at Goshen College. I am supposed to create a final project for my programming class. I am thinking about doing the game Battleship. I realize that I could find the complete code somewhere online but I would really like to write my own.I came up with a list of things I would like to try to implement into the game and a general idea of how I would like the program to run.

1. Make four 10 x 10 grids. One with stored locations for the computer's ships, one with the player's ships, and two to be displayed, keeping track of both you and the computer's guesses.
2. By using format (a,6), user/computer can guess location.
3. Tells user what ship they are placing and how big it is. User gives a star
   cordinate, then gives either up, left, or right to decide which direction
   the ship lies. This is grid one. Grid two is a stored grid of ships. That
   will be the computer's grid. The game will keep track of your guesses, 
   and put circles where
   you miss, x's where you hit and ~'s are water(spaces you haven't guessed.
   This is grid three. Grid four is the computer's guesses.
4. Random computer guess until hit. Then use algorithm to check all adjacent
   spaces until the ship is sunk.
5. Take turns
6. Display Grids three and four simultaneously.

I really just don't know where to start. I have a general idea of the logic that I would need to create the game, I just don't know where to jump in and start defining programs. 
Thanks!

Comment: you have already divided your program into modules..start working on these modules one at a time

Comment: Might I suggest `pygame`. It would make your life really easy. I still have my program from the time I made a battleship program in `pygame`.

Answer (score 2):

Your algorithm looks perfectly fine. As you aim for this to be implemented in Python, I'd start with creating simple PyGame (or other library of your choice) application, that only draws two of your grids. That will help you debug your other functionality, once you'll see it better than array dump in the console.

Alternatively, you may implement everything text-mode based just for now, and later enhance it with graphics — making your application more like "query-response", printing two grids with plain `print()` and asking for move with `raw_input()` — that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Note: the following basic design concept should work well for most board-game style games.

You need to make a lot of decisions first:

- Should it run in the command line (easiest), with a GUI toolkit, or as an OpenGL application?
- Should it have a 'game lobby' that allows starting a new game, or should it simply launch directly into the game, and exit afterwards?

If you do the easiest one (command line, launch directly into game), simply init your four matrices, and then jump into a main loop that follows the following scheme:

```
initialize_gamestate()

while True:
   print_game()
   input = player_input()
   game_logic(0, input)
   input = computer_AI()
   game_logic(1, input)
```

`game_logic()` calculates the changes caused by player number/`input`, and updates your four matrices (game state) accordingly. It would then check if one player has won, and If so, stop the main loop.

`print_game()` outputs the current gamestate.

`computer_AI()` and `player_input()` return the coordinate that has been selected by the player/AI. `computer_AI()` tries to intelligently determine the next course of action by looking at the information that would be available to player 1. `player_input()` asks the player what to do. For starting, just make your computer AI return random coordinates, and improve it later.

As a more advanced concept, you can make the number and type of players dynamic:

```
players = [
    ("mike", player_input),
    ("vladimir", computer_AI_hard)
]

initialize_gamestate(len(players))

while True:
    for number, (name, input_function) in enumerate(players):
        print(name + "'s turn")
        input = input_function(number)
        game_logic(number, input)
```

in that case, player_input would print the game state that is relevant to player `number`.